# Software to manage facebook posts

Tags: facebook

I am looking for a software which would help me manage facebook posts and schedule comments every 24 hours.

I can't find anything free at all. Any free software, selenium or python script or alike would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about comments, but as far as scheduling posts go, you may want to consider

- https://buffer.com/
- https://hootsuite.com/
- https://www.socialoomph.com/

Each of these 3 tools offer very similar functionality and it would be best to sign-up to a free trial to review them and work out which is best for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could invoking any program that lets you post to Facebok, such as [facebook-cli](https://github.com/specious/facebook-cli), with cron or anacron. You'll probably need to write a very small amount of code to retrieve and remove the text for the new post from a file or database.